# How to use a jumphost/jump server in a script

Tags: bash, ssh, proxy, dmz

I need to write a script to be able to run cmds on our test servers in our secure, off-site lab.  The problem is these test servers are behind a jump server/jump host.  Manually, I either type:

```
bash$ ssh -A jumphost
jumphost$ ssh server1
```

or I edited my personal .ssh/config file to use the jump host

```
ForwardAgent yes
Host server1
ProxyCommand ssh -q jumphost nc <ip of server1> 22
```

to access them.  How do I do this inside my script so that ssh doesn't stop/terminate at ssh -A jumphost?

I tried to run

```
ssh jumphost nc <ip of server1> 22 "ls /tmp"
```

or

```
ssh jumphost nc <ip of server1> 22
```

or

```
ssh -A jumphost nc <ip> 22
```

but it complains of a protocol mismatch.  I don't control the jump host so I can't just leave scripts/programs at a common place for people to use.  I also don't think IT will make a jump host for us to use exclusively.

Is there a way for me to run scripts thru a jump host?  Thanks in advance for your help.  If there isn't a way, I'll just tell IT they need to allow me to copy my scripts to the jump host b/c the experts on stackoverflow said it needed to be done  =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
ssh -At jumpserver ssh -At server1
```

should work. The `-t` makes sure that a pseudo-tty is allocated where needed (it may not be necessary on the second one, but I don't have a setup where I can test that at the moment, and it won't hurt). This also has the benefit that when you exit from `server1`, both sessions go away...

Answer (score 2):

Update `~/.ssh/config` file as follows,

```
Host JumpHost
    Hostname 111.255.223.108
    User jump-user
    IdentityFile ~/Keys/JumpHost.pem
    AddKeysToAgent yes

Host PrivateHost
    Hostname 120.010.111.166
    IdentityFile ~/Keys/my-private-key.pem
    User private-user
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    ProxyJump JumpHost
```

Then ssh on the command line, `ssh PrivateHost`

If you don't want to modify the config file ssh parameters can be used:

```
ssh -J jump-user@111.255.223.108 private-user@120.010.111.166 "ls /tmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Without config files, with different ports, different keys and different users:
jump host port: 2244, target host port: 2266 (ports are just examples). If standard port (22) is used, then -p/-P options can be omitted.

```
OUTPUT=$(ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p $JUMPHOST_USER@$JUMPHOST_IP -p 2244 -i jumphost_key_file" -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new $TARGETHOST_USER@$TARGETHOST_IP -p 2266 -i targethost_key_file 'command')
echo $OUTPUT
```

-oStrictHostKeyChecking option is for automatically accepting ECDSA key. If this is a security issue for you, you should take out this option, but then first time need to acknowledge manually.
Also don't forget to allow agentforwarding on jump host in sshd_config.
It may also be necessary to allow TCPForwarding as well on jump host in sshd_config, and maybe in /etc/sysctl.conf need to uncomment/enable net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1.

if you want to run a local script on the target host:

```
OUTPUT=$(ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p $JUMPHOST_USER@$JUMPHOST_IP -p 2244 -i jumphost_key_file" $TARGETHOST_USER@$TARGETHOST_IP -p 2266 -i targethost_key_file 'bash -c' <local_bash_script.sh)
echo $OUTPUT
```

scp can also be used like this:

```
scp -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p $JUMPHOST_USER@$JUMPHOST_IP -p 2244 -i jumphost_key_file" -i targethost_key_file -P 2266 local_file_to_copy.txt $TARGETHOST_USER@$TARGETHOST_IP:/tmp/new_file_name.txt
```

note capital P for port in scp command, but not in ssh! omit new_file_name.txt if you don't want to change the file name. I have this running on debian 10
Hope this helps if you don't want to maintain config files.